# Do I still need to json_decode() on the return value of wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get())?

Tags: json, http-api

I have a line `$data = file_get_contents($url);` which returns :

```
{
  "a": false,
  "b": true,
  "c": false,
  "d": true,
  "e": false,
  "f": false,
}
```

I have to do `$data = json_decode($data);`

What would I need to do to when using [WordPress's HTTP API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/http-api/) ?

`$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get($url));`

Do I still need to do `$data = json_decode($body);` ?

Comment: Yes, you would.